# Finite Extension of Integral Domains.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, extension-field, integral-domain

Let $D\subset E$ (integral domains), with fraction fields $k\subset K $.

Suppose that $E$ is integral over $D$, and $E$ is $D$-module finitely generated.

My question is:

$[K:k]$ is finite?

Thank you all.

Comment: How familiar are you with commutative algebra? What theorems do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $E$ is a finitely generated $D$-module. Say $E=De_1+\cdots+De_n$. Let's show that the field extension $k\subset K$ is finite. It is clearly algebraic (why?) and of finite type: $K=k(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ (why?).

Comment: Why $K=k(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$? I don't know how to show it.

Comment: The extension $K/k$ is algebraic since $e_i$ are integral over D? In particular algebraic over k. Is correct? Thank you.

Comment: @user126033 Yes, it's correct.

Comment: And necessarily $[K:k]\leq n$?

Comment: @user126033 I'd say that it is not necessary!